# Why is DAY_OF_WEEK adding an extra day?

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(1560049200);

cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY // this returns true

cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US) // Outputs Monday instead of Sunday.
```

Why does DAY_OF_WEEK add an extra day? It should return Sunday, but it's returning Monday.

I have tested this in I/System.out, on my Android device, and on Android Emulator. `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY` keeps returning `true`.

-EDIT-

I also tried:

```
Date date = new Date(1560049200);
date.getDay();
```

this is returning `1`.

Comment: `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY` returns false for me and outputs Sunday.

Comment: That's weird. For me it's returning true, both in the I/System.out and on my Android device.

Comment: Maybe you need to set the Locale in the getInstance method, e.g. `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);` I'm not really a Calendar expert so I'm just guessing.

Comment: @JamesKPolk it's still returning `true` for me.

Comment: I solved it by doing: `cal.setTimeInMillis((long)1560049200 * 1000);`

Comment: OK ... so the problem was the data not the code.  You were doing a millisecond conversion using a timestamp expressed in seconds.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Instant                          // Represent a moment in UTC.
.ofEpochSecond(                  // Parse a count of whole seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z.
    1_560_049_200L               // Contemporary moments are about a billion and a half seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z.
)                                // Returns a `Instant` object.
.atZone(                         // Adjust from UTC to the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
    Zone.of( "Africa/Tunis" )    // Specify the time zone in which you are interested.
)                                // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.getDayOfWeek()                  // Returns one of the seven pre-defined enum objects, one for each day of the week, Monday-Sunday. Returns a `DayOfWeek` object.
.getDisplayName(                 // Localize the presentation of the name of the day of the week.
    TextStyle.FULL ,             // Specify how long or abbreviated should the name of the day of week be.
    new Locale ( "fr" , "TN" )   // Specify the human language and cultural norms to use in translating the name of the day of week.
)                                // Returns a `String` object.
```

> samedi

## Problems

- Your input is apparently a **count of whole seconds**, not [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond).
- You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the **modern *java.time*** classes.
- You are implicitly introducing **time zone** issues without addressing them head on. Time zone is crucial in perceiving a date (and day-of-week).

## java.time

Your input number `1_560_049_200L` is apparently a count of whole seconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC. Your code was parsing them as a count of milliseconds by mistake.

Parse as an `Instant`.

```
Instant instan = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_560_049_200L ) ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2019-06-09T03:00:00Z

Adjust to the time zone through which you want to perceive a date, and therefore a day-of-week.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2019-06-08T23:00-04:00[America/Montreal]

Notice the difference in date: **the 9th in UTC versus the 8th in Québec**. Keep in mind: For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. In the east it is “tomorrow” while still “yesterday” in the west.

A different date means a different day-of-week. While **Saturday in Québec, it is simultaneously Sunday in Paris**, France. This is why specifying a time zone is crucial.

Extract the day-of-week.

```
DayOfWeek dow = zdt.getDayOfWeek() ;
```

> dow.toString(): SATURDAY

Localize the name of the day-of-week.

```
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

> samedi

Or, `Locale.US` for the United States.

```
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US );
```

> Saturday

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]